# `dotnet new` throws 401 unauthorized without version on package name

Tags: .net-core, nuget, dotnet-sdk

So I have a [dotnet template](https://github.com/pdevito3/foundation.api) that is [published to nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Foundation.Api/), but it is only getting installed when running the install command with the version like so: `dotnet new --install Foundation.Api::0.3.0`. When I run the install command without the version `dotnet new --install Foundation.Api`, it gives me a 401 unauthorized. Is there some kind of setting I need to add to my csproj? I'm 99% i've done this before without the version and it's ran just fine.

Here's the full error:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp1.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [C:\Users\Paul\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v5.0.100\scratch\restore.csproj]
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/94b81536-897b-42e6-8b47-bca8f94285e6/nuget/v3/flat2/foundation.api/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/94b81536-897b-42e6-8b47-bca8f94285e6/nuget/v3/flat2/foundation.api/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'Foundation.Api' from remote source 'https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/94b81536-897b-42e6-8b47-bca8f94285e6/nuget/v3/flat2/foundation.api/index.json'. [C:\Users\Paul\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v5.0.100\scratch\restore.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\Paul\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v5.0.100\scratch\restore.csproj]
```

Comment: you have azure devops as nuget source, check if your nuget is in the artifacts feed, make sure you have a valid token or change your nuget.conf if you actually want to use another source.

Comment: weird. where would i set that up? I don't have any azure devops settings in my csproj (or anywhere else as far as i know)

Comment: do you have a nuget.config file?

Comment: no, my nuget config is in my csproj. you can see the repo in the link of the question for the exact setup

Comment: hmm, i think it was trying to hit my company's vs site instead of the normal nuget site for some reason. might be a local variable. regardless, all good. thanks